# AS3 - Fullscreen that uses full browser window

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

My flash program isn't using the full browser window, even while in full-screen mode. It uses the full height but not the full width. I end up with a large chunk of white space. I have the following code for full-screen mode:

```
function fullscreenOnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
      stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT
      stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

I also have some code to set the background color:

```
//set the background
graphics.beginFill(0x777777);
graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
graphics.endFill();
```

So the problem is that the stage's width isn't the full size of the browser. I'm using Flash Builder 4.6 is there a way to set the stage's parameters to allow for true full-screen?

Comment: Is that `//set the background` script placed within a stage resize listener?

Comment: it isn't. I'll try that and get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: Still the same. I added `stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE && Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageResize);
   function onStageResize(e:Event):void 
   {
    //set the background
    graphics.beginFill(0x777777);
    graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    graphics.endFill();
   }`

Comment: Do you actually run the code inside onStageResize? I am not sure the syntax **Event.RESIZE && Event.ENTER_FRAME** is correct.

Comment: when its only Event.RESIZE it is never ran. When it is Event.RESIZE && Event.ENTER_FRAME it does run. I wasn't sure you could do that either but it looks like you can. I'll try it with two different functions just to be sure.

Comment: It looks like you can or/and those together. Also, it is properly resizing up until it hits the maximum size (it seems like 800 X 800). After that there is just more white space on the right of the browser. The issue must be that the stage's width isn't the full size of the browsers width.

Comment: "when its only Event.RESIZE it is never ran. When it is Event.RESIZE && Event.ENTER_FRAME it does run" seems really strange to me.  Just going by the logic, if Event.RESIZE never happens, how in the is the && function firing off ever? Maybe I just don't understand that syntax when it is in the event listener.  Also make sure that your swf is not locked to an aspect ratio (maybe it is maximizing the height then setting the width to correspond to that height with the aspect ratio of your swf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be because of the [scaling mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e31.html#WS0D75B487-23B9-402d-A52D-CB3C4CEB9EE4). Try changing the stage's scaleMode to StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER, (or experiment with the other scale modes if StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER is not what you are looking for.)

Comment: I think that did it, I'll double check though.

Comment: Yes, I think it is only possible with html.

Comment: You were spot on. The default stage width/height when scaling is turned on is evidently very small (500 x 500). With scaling turned off the stageWidth and stageHeight are now taking up the full window (1600 X 754).