# How to Set stage size by screen resolution?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i want to create a flash flip-book.
How do i set the flash size to be according to screen resolution?
Because i want to strech an image to fill the entire sreen.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318179/as3-fullscreen-that-uses-full-browser-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the stage to full screen: `stage.DisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`
Set the scaling to show all: `stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;`

You can't directly set Stage width and height, because they are read only.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i get rid of the of windows toolbar?